# Uncaught TypeError: setImmediate is not a function

Tags: reactjs, vite, react-functional-component, inertiajs, react-draft-wysiwyg

I am using a React TextEditor package [React Draft Wysiwyg](https://jpuri.github.io/react-draft-wysiwyg/#/).

Here is the implementation.

```
export default function TextEditor() {
    const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(() =>
        EditorState.createEmpty()
    );

    const handleEditorState = editorState => {
        setEditorState(editorState);
    };

    return (
        <Editor
            editorState={editorState}
            toolbarClassName="toolbarClassName"
            wrapperClassName="wrapperClassName"
            editorClassName="editorClassName"
            onEditorStateChange={handleEditorState}
        />
    );
}
```

vite.config.js

```
plugins: [
    laravel({
        input: "resources/js/app.jsx",
        ssr: "resources/js/ssr.jsx",
        refresh: true,
    }),
    react(),
],
define: {
    global: {},
},
```

And it run into an console error
[image: Uncaught TypeError: setImmediate is not a function.]

Here is the original implementation article from Medium [article](https://medium.com/@chetansain86/how-to-integrate-rich-text-editor-react-draft-wysiwyg-to-react-app-d40486f469f4)

Comment: What version of `react-draft-wysiwyg` are you using? Are you making any reference to `setImmediate` in your code?

Comment: The package is the latest version 1.15.0, I don't have any reference using setImmediate function.

Comment: This looks like an issue with the underlying dependency packages: https://github.com/facebookarchive/draft-js/issues/2127

This package (and the packages it depends on) look stale and contain issues. I would look for an alternative.